# SQL Server make backup to different machine

Tags: sql-server, backup

I have a problem with creating SQL Server backups. I would like them to be stored on network share rather than harddrive, but passing network share URN makes them fail. Is there any way that I can do it other than harddrive mapping?

Comment: What does "makes them fail" mean?

Comment: They error out, code 5 with no error message.

Comment: don't you have the shared network path for that location? "\\machinename\Drivename\folderName\" or you already tried this and that is also not working? if the back up is happening by SQL JOB make sure the SQL SERVER AGENT has permissions to access that location. If you are doing it manually from SSMS as query then the user you logged in to SSMS should also have the access to that location.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure that the log on account used for the SQL Server service has access to the shared folder.  On the server...

```
Click Start -> Run
Type services.msc
Scroll down to SQL Server
Right Click -> Properties
Click on "Log On" tab.
Verify that the log on account has access to the shared folder.
```